# What is the difference between the IDE and JDK and when do you use each one?

Tags: java, ide, difference

What is the difference between the IDE and JDK and when do you use each one?

Comment: What is the difference between an IDE and an <everything else> in any other language?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit.

Comment: Please don't use StackOveflow as an excuse for not buying a technical dictionary ... or learning how to use Google.

Comment: @LoloOo In short terms, in your case, NetBeans is an IDE. The JDK is the set of tools that allow you to write, compile and run Java code. The IDE relies on the JDK and has features to speed up your development activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDK means Java Development Kit. You need it to compile java codes. You can use a text editor to write code and execute it using terminal if you have installed JDK.
An IDE is used for ease of coding. IDEs support code completion,syntax highlighting etc. You need JDK installed for using IDE.