# Gradle's involvement in the Android build process

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to understand the timeline of an Android app from the source code to the final `.apk` file. This is how I imagine it:

[image]

1. The **JVM** compiles all of my `.java` & `.kt` files to seperate `.class` files and convert the Java/Kotlin code directly to Java bytecode. The JVM also converts my libraries/dependencies (which are `.jar` files or `.java`/`.kt` files) into Java Bytecode.
2. **Gradle** then joins the process after all the source code has been converted into Bytecode. It builds the project by merging all of the `.class` files together into one `.dex` file. (Sometimes it also builds other files depending on Gradle configuration).
3. Gradle then creates an `.apk` file with the `.dex` file and other files - which is then ready to be deployed onto an Android device.

Can someone tell me if this is not accurate or if I have skipped a step?

Comment: JVM is a runtime environment for desktops and servers; I assume that you mean the JDK where you have JVM). Gradle orchestrates the entire build process. The JDK does not compile Kotlin code. There may be more than one `.dex` file. You are missing build variants, code generation, etc. And I assume that skipping resources, manifests, assets, etc. was intentional (to focus on Java/Kotlin source).

Comment: "JDK does not compile Kotlin code" - Many answers I've seen say the JDK contains the Java Compiler which converts the Java code to Bytecode - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28514776/6733153

Comment: Java != Kotlin. A Java compiler compiles Java code. A Kotlin compiler compiles Kotlin code.